# What does this list contain in Python, or is it a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, tuples

I know that lists in Python are surrounded by square brackets `[]`.

I had an output that looked something like the following:

```
[(451,165,76,-77,[98,42])]
```

Is this a list of a tuple? How can we access the items?

Thanks.

Comment: Where exactly does the output come from? You have selected the `numpy` tag, that's why I'm curious if it's that simple.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `numpy` and `arrays`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give it a try in a terminal, it's all self-explanatory:

```
>>> x = [(451,165,76,-77,[98,42])]
>>> type(x)
<type 'list'>
>>> x[0]
(451, 165, 76, -77, [98, 42])
>>> x[0][1]
165
>>> x[0][4]
[98, 42]
>>> type(x[0][4])
<type 'list'>
>>> x[0][4][1]
42
```

Anyway, just because the output looks like a list, it doesn't need to be a list. It can be a more complex data structure (an object of some user-defined class) that specifies how to be printed by overloading `__str__()` or `__repr__()` (see [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**str**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) for details)

Answer (score 2):

This is a `list` containing a `tuple` which has the first four elements as  `integers` and the last `element` as a `list` of `2` `integers`.

You can access all the values by `indexing` correctly. Here are some examples:

```
>>> l = [(451,165,76,-77,[98,42])]
>>> l[0]
(451, 165, 76, -77, [98, 42])
>>> l[0][0]
451
>>> l[0][1]
165
>>> l[0][3]
-77
>>> l[0][4]
[98, 42]
>>> l[0][4][0]
98
>>> l[0][4][1]
42
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is a list of a tuple.

```
a = [(451,165,76,-77,[98,42])]
type(a)     #> list
type(a[0])  #> tuple
```

You would access the first item of the tuple like this:

```
a[0][0]     #> 451
```

And the last item of the tuple is a list:

```
a[0][4]     #> [98, 42]
```

And to access the elements of that list, you just add another layer of brackets:

```
a[0][4][0]  #> 98
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a list that contains one tuple, that himself contains 5 elements, of which one of them is a table.

To access:

```
a=[(451,165,76,-77,[98,42])]

a[0][0][2]
```

will return 76

```
a[0][0][4][0]
```

will return 98

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a list containing **one** element. And -as you mentioned correctly- this element is a tuple. A tuple is used in this case, because its last element is a list as well (tuples are suitable to store heterogenous data).

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote a type inspector awhile back that has served me well, because as asked we can only guess as to the type of the data when it's output as a string. For all we know it could be an object of type `Person` or `Frombulate` who chooses to `str()` as given.

```
def type_diver(obj, prefix="", index = ""):
    print "%s'%s': %s%s" % (prefix, obj, type(obj), " - Accessible via " + index if index else "")
    if not isinstance(obj, str):
        try:
            for ind, elem in enumerate(obj):
                type_diver(elem, " " * len(prefix) + "|---", index + "[%s]" % ind)
        except TypeError:
            pass  # Don't call recursively on non-iterable objects
```

Which, for a basic python object gives, on your input:

```
'[(451, 165, 76, -77, [98, 42])]': <type 'list'>
|---'(451, 165, 76, -77, [98, 42])': <type 'tuple'> - Accessible via [0]
    |---'451': <type 'int'> - Accessible via [0][0]
    |---'165': <type 'int'> - Accessible via [0][1]
    |---'76': <type 'int'> - Accessible via [0][2]
    |---'-77': <type 'int'> - Accessible via [0][3]
    |---'[98, 42]': <type 'list'> - Accessible via [0][4]
        |---'98': <type 'int'> - Accessible via [0][4][0]
        |---'42': <type 'int'> - Accessible via [0][4][1]
```

But I could write a custom class which `str()` output looks like that. The only way to know is to ask.

If your data is as [hpaulj suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47539537/3579910) [a numpy array], you might see something like:

```
'[(451, 165, 76, -77, [98, 42])]': <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
|---'(451, 165, 76, -77, [98, 42])': <type 'numpy.void'> - Accessible via [0]
    |---'451': <type 'numpy.int32'> - Accessible via [0][0]
    |---'165': <type 'numpy.int32'> - Accessible via [0][1]
    |---'76': <type 'numpy.int32'> - Accessible via [0][2]
    |---'-77': <type 'numpy.int32'> - Accessible via [0][3]
    |---'[98 42]': <type 'numpy.ndarray'> - Accessible via [0][4]
        |---'98': <type 'numpy.int32'> - Accessible via [0][4][0]
        |---'42': <type 'numpy.int32'> - Accessible via [0][4][1]
```

Given everyone will have a different object they are interested in typing, this is a more general solution. It does, however, only investigate iterable objects.

Comment: Fails for `obj = [None]; obj[0] = obj; type_diver(obj)` :P

Comment: Add as much error handling as you desire. It serves it's purpose well.

Answer (score 0):

While the straight forward Python description is a list with a tuple that contains integers and list, the display is also consistent with a `numpy` structured array.

Define a compound dtype:

```
In [596]: dt = np.dtype('i,i,i,i,(2)i')
In [597]: dt
Out[597]: dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4', (2,))])
```

Make an array with this list input.  Data for a compound dtype (structured array) is in the form of a list of tuples.  Each tuple represents the data of a record or element of the array:

```
In [598]: arr = np.array([(451,165,76,-77,[98,42])], dtype=dt)
In [599]: arr
Out[599]: 
array([(451, 165, 76, -77, [98, 42])],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4', (2,))])
```

Print of this array looks just like the question:

```
In [600]: print(arr)
[(451, 165, 76, -77, [98, 42])]
```

This is a 1 element array with 5 fields.  The last field has shape (2,), in effect a 2 element array.

```
In [601]: arr['f4']
Out[601]: array([[98, 42]], dtype=int32)
In [602]: _.shape
Out[602]: (1, 2)
```

Comment: This is the sort of situation I in which I would use the type inspector in my answer: we can only guess as to the type of the data when it's output as a string. I suspect you are correct in your guess, however, as the op tagged `numpy`.